# Display chart after form submit via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I need to display a report with some data from the server and this also includes a chart.. im trying to send the json data using $.getJSON once the form is already submitted but for some reason im not even able to echo out $_GET[rep] to make sure im recieving the correct data.. below is the php code and here is the js http://jsfiddle.net/f8rGb/2/

PHP CODE

```
  if (isset($_POST["search"]) and $_POST["search"] == "go"){

     $name = $_POST['term'];

     $project = new Project();
     $pro = $project->get_project($name);  
     $serv = $project->get_project_service_by_id($pro);

     // DOING this to make sure i recieve the variable 
        // echo $_GET['rep'];

        if(isset($_GET['rep']))
        die(json_encode($serv)); 

     }
```

JS CODE

```
   function searchProjectsRep() {

   // TRIGGERING THIS FUNCTION IN THE ONSUBMIT EVENT OF THE FORM

   var datos = $('#formProjectsRepSearch').serialize();
   var uri = $('#formProjectsRepSearch').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        data: datos,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#ajaxProjectsRep').html(resp);
            projectChart();
        }
 });
 }

 // CHART FUNCTION

 function projectChart(){

 $.getJSON('controller.php?rep=1', function(data) { 

    options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_div',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Datos de proyecto'
    },

    series: []
    };
       var statusCount = {},
       serie1 = [];

       data.forEach(function(e) {
       statusCount[e.status] = 1 + (statusCount[e.status] || 0);
    });

    $.each(statusCount, function(status, count) {
    serie1.push( [status, count] );
    });
    options.series.push({data: serie1});

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
  }
```

Comment: For starters, have you tried `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: Wow, returning a `$_GET` variable inside a condition that checks if a `$_POST` request was done. How do you do both at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do either a `POST` request, or a `GET` request, not both at the same time, so don't return the content of the `GET` variable inside a function that checks if a `POST` request was done :

```
if ( isset($_POST["search"]) && trim( $_POST["search"] ) == "go" ){ 
    $name    = $_POST['term'];
    $project = new Project();
    $pro     = $project->get_project($name);  
    $serv    = $project->get_project_service_by_id($pro);
    exit;
}

if(isset($_GET['rep']))
    echo json_encode($serv); 
    exit;
}
```

On the other hand, what's the point of making two ajax calls, just return the data in the first one where the form is submitted ?

Comment: If i remove if(isset($_GET['rep'])) from the first if statement like you did i get Undefined variable: serv. Also i dont know what you mean  with returning the data in the first ajax call.. thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Yes you do, but calling the PHP file with another ajax call would load the file again, so you just can't send a POST request with a form to get some data, and then just do another ajax call and expect the data from the first ajax call to be returned. You should do everything in the first ajax call, just add the "rep" variable and retutn the JSON.